# getting git difference of only the parent folder

Tags: linux, git, unix, sed

I am trying to get a git difference of only the parent folders. this is my git diff output:

```
git diff --dirstat=files,0 HEAD^ HEAD | awk '{print $2}' 
aws_app1_service/app/models/
aws_app1_service/app/views/
aws_app1_service/app/
aws_app2_service/config/
aws_app2_service/k8s_resources/
aws_app2_service/tests/steps/
aws_app2_service/tests/
aws_app3_service/
aws_app4_service/
```

after this, i want to use sed to filter only the leftmost part before slash and do a sort | unique after that
i.e. the final output should be like this:

```
aws_app1_service
aws_app2_service
aws_app3_service
aws_app4_service
```

Can anyone please tell me what should be the proper usage of sed command to get this desired output? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Hidden in the middle of `git help diff` :

there is a command that lists "differences at top level without recursing" :

```
git diff-tree HEAD^ HEAD
git diff-tree --name-only HEAD^ HEAD
```

It compares two *trees* (technical git term for "directories"), so you can use it for any directories in the repo :

```
git diff-tree HEAD^:aws_app1_service/app HEAD:aws_app1_service/app

# any pair of directories works :
git diff-tree HEAD:aws_app2_service/config HEAD:aws_app1_service/config
git diff-tree develop:aws_app2_service/config master:aws_app1_service/app/views
# etc ...
```

---

To complete the command you were trying :

```
git diff --name-only HEAD^ HEAD |\   # list the name of *all* differing files
    cut -d / -f 1 |\   # one of many ways to get 'the chunk until the first "/"'
    sort -u            # remove repetitions
```

Answer (score 0):

try this with awk (without entering another command):

```
git diff --dirstat=files,0 HEAD^ HEAD | awk '{split($2,a,"/"); print a[1]}'
```

I split column 2 '$2' in an array 'a' with the '/' separator then I display the first index of the array a[1].

Answer (score 0):

An approach could be piping the output of awk to cut like this

```
git diff --dirstat=files,0 HEAD^ HEAD | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d "/" -f1
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed 's~/.*~~' | sort -u` to replace everything starting with first slash with nothing

or

`grep -o '^[^/]* | sort -u` to only print everything before first slash

Assuming you don't have `%`  in directory names you could also look this simple look-behind expression:

```
git diff --dirstat=files,0 --format= HEAD^ HEAD | grep -Po '(?<=% )[^/]+' | sort -u
```